# Is it possible to nest dll references to avoid requiring access to the original uncompiled code?

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, labview, dllexport

I'm trying to import C++ functions from an instrument SDK into LabVIEW, and I'm running into issues with function decorations. I have a header file, the dll, a lib, and a .exp file. Unfortunately, I only have the function declarations in the header. If I had the definitions, I'd recompile the dll using the "extern C" flag I've read about.

I feel like I should be able to wrap the SDK's dll in some way using a definitions file or something to translate the compiled function names and effectively "unmangle" them for LabVIEW. Something (very loosely) like:

```
myFunc(arg){
?myFunc@Class@namespace@@otherstuff(arg);
}
```

However, I haven't been able to find any discussion about this anywhere I've looked. It's entirely possible that it's abstracted enough that I don't recognize it when I see it, but I feel like it's more likely there's a reason this isn't done.

So, that's my question: **can [referencing one dll from another] be done, since I've never seen dll imports combined with exports, and could I do that to get around the need to recompile the dll from the original code?**

I'm guessing no, but I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: DLLs can load other DLLs, yes. You shouldn't need to do anything fancy. Think about the fact that your C++ DLLs are probably _already_ loading the C++ and/or C runtime libraries as DLLs, and possibly others such as stuff from Windows system32. But a DLL does NOT export other DLL interfaces, if that's what you're asking. If you want to make any of that stuff available via your own DLL for convenience, you need to wrap it and export your wrappers.

Comment: You have the header so you should be able to just call the functions like how they are declared in the header file? and the compiler will mangle the names for you?

Comment: The whole point of having the .lib file for a .dll is that it - together with the .h - allows other modules to reference it without the need for source code.

Comment: @paddy That's a good point. I believe I'm trying to understand how to wrap the existing DLL, since I can't simply recompile it with a C-friendly structuring.

Comment: @user253751 In C++, yes. Unfortunately, LabVIEW isn't smart enough to do this when I try to import the dll as an external library. The way it's mangled is apparently compiler-specific, so LabVIEW doesn't even bother. I need my dll to be in C format.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError True, but LabVIEW isn't doing that when I set it up that way. From what I've read, I really need to get my dll in a format so it's *just* the dll and the header file.

Comment: @CoilKid I mean in your wrapper DLL you can just call the function.

Comment: @user253751 I figured that out, but thanks. My new issue is making the DLL usable without shipping every header for every dependency. I think I've done something wrong, 'cause I shouldn't have to ship the cmath file with my DLL (for example)